# Android Studio Generate Signed Bundle: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, keystore, jarsigner

I have been checking all over the internet and nothing seems to be working. In Android Studio, once I click Build -> Generate Signed Bundle I all of a sudden get the issue stated above. The thing is, I was able to generate a signed bundle just a few days ago and I don't know why I am getting this error all of a sudden!

I did the following to make sure I have the passwords right:

1. I went to the terminal and changed the keystore file password.
2. I went to the terminal and changed the key_alias password.
3. I made sure the keystore and key_alias passwords are the same. I saw this in one stackoverflow post.
4. I even went to lengths as changing the keystore file altogother and new alias and I still get the same error.

I am at a loss on what to do.

Comment: Make sure you specified the correct `storePassword` and `keyPassword` in the `signingConfigs` section in `build.gradle`.

Comment: yes they are correct. i made sure of that too. i was able to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: I went to Gradle->:app->Tasks->Clean then afterwards I ran the Gradle->:app->Tasks->Build and problem got solved

Comment: Cool, it Worked, i think this is an Android Studio issue, if you type wrong password once and then even we typed the correct password it will throw error .